# Transpose the row data into a single row based on a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, row, transpose

I have a table structure as below.

[image]

Each name has multiple parentids. i want to create a query to Display the row values of column ID and Name in a single row based on parentid something like below.
[image]

Please help me how to achieve this. this is one of the question asked in interview

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @yitzhak create table #data
(ID int,
Name varchar(10),
parentid int)

insert into #data values
(1,'A',1),
(1,'A',2),
(2,'B',3),
(3,'C',2),
(2,'B',4),
(4,'D',2),
(4,'D',1)

Comment: @squillman No this seems different